# Tox discarding pythonpath, good idea to explicitely reset it?

Tags: python, virtualenv, tox

In my `virtualenv` activation, I like to set `export PYTHONPATH=<mypath>` so that I can run scripts directly.
Now when I run `tox` from within the virtualenv, I get the following warning in alarming red color:

```
WARNING: Discarding $PYTHONPATH from environment, to override specify PYTHONPATH in 'passenv' in your configuration.
```

I do understand the warning and I am fine with tox overriding PYTHONPATH, but the warning is annoying. I *could* leave the venv and run `tox` without it, but that is also annoying.

Is it a good idea to explicitely zero `PYTHONPATH=""` when running tox?

```
[testenv]
# Explicitely reset pythonpath to avoid the "discarding" warning
setenv = PYTHONPATH = ""
```

Does this affect other things which `tox` may want to do with the path, which I am not aware about yet?